# How to make board one dimensional c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have previously created a board for a domineering game but now I am trying to make the board one dimensional for a game called toads and frogs and I don't know where to start, if it is possible that I don't have to include an array to make the one dimensional then that would be good.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{  
// specify default value to fill the vector elements
int mapSize = 8;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int horizontal = 0;
int vertical = 0;

cout << "Enter the size of board => ";
cin >> mapSize;

vector< vector<char> > board(mapSize, vector<char>(mapSize, 'e'));
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++) {
        cout << board[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have a two dimensional board created by use of a nested vector.
You use `vector<vector<char>> board(mapSize, vector<char>(mapSize, 'e'));` which creates a list containing lists, using the vector constructor `vector<E>(size_type n, const value_type& val)`. This means the vector contains `n` elements of type `E` that are copies of `val`.

For example, in the case of `vector<int>(5, 10)`, the list created will look like this `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]`
In your code, it will become more like `[['e', 'e', 'e'], ['e', 'e', 'e'], ['e', 'e', 'e']]` for `mapSize = 3` for example.

To make one dimensional, you simply need to make it an ordinary list rather than a list of lists. For example `vector<char> board(mapSize, 'e')` to make a simple `['e', 'e', 'e']`.

This also means when printing the code, access will be made in one dimension - Eg. `board[i]` will get the value at that space.